# How to make a conditional labeling from bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a grouped bar chart with a lot of information in it.
[image]

This one is the worst example, I know it looks like this is the wrong way to display the information, but with the other samples it worked just fine and I need this one to show the difference.
My problem are the labels from the bars.

As you can see the smallr bars are not readable at all.
I wanted to exlude bars with a count < 10 from labeling, but it does not quite work as I expected.

I tried plotting with the following code:

```
aggregated_data <- data_dia %>%
  group_by(INDEX, BIN) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

ggplot(data=data_dia, aes(x=factor(INDEX), y=stat(count), 
                          group=factor(BIN), fill=factor(BIN)))+
  geom_bar()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen","darkred"), labels = c("A", "B"))+
  labs(title=oe, y="Häufigkeit", x="Index", fill="A or B")+
  geom_text(aes(label= if_else(count > 10, count, NA)), stat="count",  position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), color="white")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),legend.position="bottom")
```

My idea was that `label= if_else(count > 10, count, NA)` would set an "empty" label for all bars which have a count < 10.
However, this error occurs:
comparison (>) is possible only for atomic and list types

Is there any other possibility to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't just use `count` on its own. You need `after_stat(count)`. For example `if_else(after_stat(count) > 10, after_stat(count), '')`

Comment: Thanks!

First I had another error because I couldn't combine a double with logical (count with NA) but I just had to update the dplyr lib. Now it works as intended :)